# Issues with connecting to mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to connect to a database using this code:

```
Dim SQL as String = "server=mysqld; user id=root; password=mysql; database=[name]"
```

The error:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

Here is my mysql workbench setup:

```
my connection = localhost
User = root, Host = localhost:3306
```

and my server instance:

```
mysqld@localhost
Local type: windows
```

Answer (score 0):

Server =localhost; Port =3306; Database =myDataBase; Uid =root; Pwd =mysql;

Source: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: Then I get this: "There was an error updating the database: Fatal error encountered during command execution."

thanks for your response.

Comment: That ("fatal error during command execution") would mean you are connected to the database and send either an invalid sql statement or something mysql cannot handle.

Answer (score 0):

You probably got the wrong server name.Usually in xml configuration files the server always is a ip address or a computer name.You can reference the manual related JDBC or MySQL to get through.